# How to document a callback function parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, typedoc, tsdoc

I am using [TypeDoc](https://typedoc.org/) to generate documentation from my typescript files. Let say I have this source code

```
/**
 * Some function
 * @param bar some callback function
 */
export function foo(bar:(x:number)=>void)
{

}
```

Which gives me this output

[image: generated documentation]

I could have make an extra type for bar then document it

```
/**
 * @param x callback parameter
 */
export type Bar = (x:number)=>void

/**
 * Some function
 * @param bar some callback function
 */
 export function foo(bar:Bar)
 {
 
 }
```

which output

[image: documentation of foo with Bar declared]
[image: documentation of Bar]

But it would look nicer if the documentation of a callback can be inlined. Is it possible to document `x` without declaring an extra type just for the callback?

Comment: I'd like to see what an extra type would look like... as I can't seem to get it to work even with the new type?

Comment: @caTS edited the question for what I mean for an extra type